# Fast refresh materialized view based on non-fast refresh view

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I've found that I can have two tables and create a `fast refresh on commit` `materialized view` based on those tables joined.

What I would like to do however is to make a `fast refresh on commit` materialized view based on the following:

(1) A table JOINED TO
(2) A `complete refresh on demand` materialized view which itself is based on other views (ordinary views, that is).

When I try to this I get error `ORA-12053`, which talked about entries in the `from` clause having dependencies on each other, even when they clearly don't.

I can work around this by replacing (2) with an ordinary table, and just doing a bulk insert into this table instead of refreshing the materialized view. However, I'd rather not do this if not necessary.

I'll try to work on a minimal example that illustrates the error, but if you could give me an idea of whether what I want to do is possible (preferably by an example) or not possible that would be great.

Comment: it is a interesting question, pls add the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these facts to understand the error.

1. The `Fast Refresh on Commit` materialized view is refreshed row by
   row based on changes made on base tables.
2. The `Refresh Complete on Demand` materialized view is refreshed by
   truncate the destination table and reinsert everything.
3. The refresh of the upper materialized view won't be possible because
   oracle can't track changes on table 2 (that is, the refresh complete
   materialized view.)

Comment: Both the (1) table and (2) `complete refresh on demand` materialized view had materialized view logs on them, so I'm not sure why I can't fast refresh from a materialized view but can fast refresh if I just truncate the table and reinsert manually?

Comment: you can fast refresh after truncate and commit, but the "truncate" does not replicate on target materialized view. You'll got only inserts in the materialized view. This is not permitted in nested materialized views, because it is let's say, strange. It will not reflect the base tables data.

Answer (score 0):

There are restrictions on nested materialized views. I described them in [this blogpost](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2009/08/fast-refreshable-materialized-view.html). The ORA-12053 is the result of not satisfying the first restriction of nested MV's. Making the underlying MV more complex (a join, aggregate or union all MV), is a solution.

Regards,
Rob.